# Game works fine on unity but not on android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an application and I am building it on unity. It is a review app which sends the review directly to the owner's email address. The problem is that the app works fine when it is being played on Unity, the email is sent all fine but the same doesn't happen on mobile-device. I am still a novice in coding.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


public class mono_gmail : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject gameController;


public void onSubmitButton()
{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("sender_emailId");
    mail.To.Add("recipient_EmailId");
    mail.Subject = "Review";
    mail.Body = gameController.GetComponent<AppController>().reviewSend;

    SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtpServer.Port = 587;
    smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender_emailId", "sender_pass") as ICredentialsByHost;
    smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };
    smtpServer.Send(mail);
    Debug.Log("success");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open player setting in Editor and change API compatibility level to NET 2.0 (Don't use NET 2.0 subset this will strip some APIs of don't mistaken) build again and deploy. VOILA your problem is gone :-D